# What were the four Items I sent to my neighbor?

Tags: little-inferno

During my time playing with my Little Inferno Entertainment Fireplace, I have been in contact with my neighbour and sent her (Sugar Plumps) 4 letters with items attached.

> Now I have received a letter that tells me, in order to progress, I need to burn those 4 items together.

What items did I send to my neighbour throughout the game?

Comment: They send you another letter that tells you. I completely forgot myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "End Combo" consists of the four items that the character sends Sugar Plumps over the course of the entire game

- the Broken Magnet
- the Jar of Fireflies
- the Toy Exterminator
- Fashionable Sunglasses.

[Source](http://little-inferno.wikia.com/wiki/End_Combo)

Comment: If you keep burning items, eventually you get a letter explicitly telling you which items to burn.